# Adding New Rows with Equally Spaced Values Between Existing Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have sourced annual GDP values and wish to estimate the monthly GDP values by creating 11 rows between existing entries and filling each with an equal incremental step size between successive annual entries. Below outlines the desired transformation.

Start:

```
 Period     Russia    India
  1997     1.00e12   2.45e11
  1998     1.12e12   2.33e11
  1999     1.00e12   2.45e11
```

End:

```
   Period      Russia    India
  12/1997     1.00e12   2.45e11
  01/1998     1.01e12   2.44e11
  02/1998     1.02e12   2.43e11
 ...............................
 ...............................
  12/1998     1.12e12   2.33e11
  01/1998     1.11e12   2.34e11
  02/1998     1.10e12   2.35e11
 ...............................
 ...............................
  12/1999     1.00e12   2.45e11
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, resample:
    df.resample('1M')

then interpolate:

```
 df.Russia = df.Russia.interpolate()
 df.India = df.India.interpolate()
```

(you can interpolate all the relevant columns together):

```
 df = df.interpolate()
```